# How can I compare for equality the values of two lists in one loop?

Tags: python, list, loops, python-itertools

So I want to make this so I can check if another code is working, but I keep getting this error:

```
'list index out of range'
```

For the following code:

```
for L1[i] in range(0, len(L1)):
    if L1[i]==L2[i]:
        L1[i]='ok'
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: maybe you should try `for i in range(...` and not `L1[i] in range`.

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: What does it mean for two lists to be "equal"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is Python, there are two problems:

1. You only want to specify `i` in the beginning of the `for`-loop.
2. `L2` may not have as many items as `L1`.

---

```
for i in range(0, len(L1)):
    try:
        if L1[i] == L2[i]:
            L1[i] = 'ok'
    except IndexError:
        break
```

As Frederik points out, you could use `enumerate` as well:

```
for i, l1 in enumerate(L1):
    try:
        if L[i] == L2[i]:
            L1[i] = 'ok'
    except:
        break
```

In my opinion, the increase in readability of `enumerate` over `range` is mostly offset by defining an extra variable (`l1`) which you never use. But it is just my opinion.

---

One last option, which may be best, is to use `zip` to merge the two lists (`zip` truncates the longer of the two):

```
for i, l1, l2 in enumerate( zip(L1, L2) ):
    if l1 == l2:
        L1[i] = 'ok'
```

Comment: `enumerate` just adds an unnecessary layer of code, given the requirement to assign to `L1[i]` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You probably are looking for something more like this. I recommend prevalidating your list lengths are equal so that your loop doesn't fall over.

```
assert len(L1) == len(L2)

for i in range(len(L1)):
    if L1[i] == L2[i]:
        L1[i] = 'ok'
```

Alternately, if it is acceptable for your lists to be of different lengths, simply take the minimum of the two lengths as your exclusive upper bound.

```
upper_bound = min(len(L1), len(L2))
for i in range(upper_bound):
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
import itertools
zipped_pairs = itertools.izip_longest(L1, L2, fillvalue=object()) # generator of pairs (L1[n],L2[n])
equals_tests = (a == b for a,b in zipped_pairs) # perform equality test on each pair
all_equal = all(equals_tests) # True if all of the equals_tests items are True
```

Or in one line:

```
all((a == b for a,b in itertools.izip_longest(L1, L2, fillvalue=object()))
```

Note that this will ultimately return false whenever L1 and L2 are of different lengths. If you want to have something else, alter the `equals_tests` step to use the test you prefer. You may also need to use a different `fillvalue` parameter for `izip_longest`.

In fact, here's a version which will treat an empty place as equal to anything:

```
nonce = object()
all(((a == b) or (nonce in (a,b)) for a,b in itertools.izip_longest(L1, L2, fillvalue=nonce))
```

Comment: Yeah, that's probably a better idea